# Explaination for はずです?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the difference between

> 貴方{あなた}には、会うべき御方{おかた}がいるはずです。

and

> 貴方{あなた}には、会うべき御方{おかた}がいる。（or います for politeness）

?

According to [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99) はずです means "be supposed or expected to (do)" but that does not go in my head for some reason.

Without はずです the sentence means: `"There is someone you should meet."`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the difference.

> 会うべき人がいます。／会うべき人がいる。
>   There is someone you should meet.
>
> 会うべき人がいるはずです。／会うべき人がいるはずだ。
>   There must be someone you should meet.
>   I believe there is someone you should meet.

This はず(だ) is a basic grammatical pattern, so please read the following articles:

- [Maggie Sensei: How to use はず ( = hazu)](http://maggiesensei.com/2012/11/14/request-lesson-how-and-when-to-use-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9Ahazu/)
- [Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese: Things that should be a certain way](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/should)

Not to be confused with べき, which can be also translated to "should". べき refers to one's obligation or correct choice, whereas はず refers to one's belief or expectation about some fact.

Answer (score 0):

> 貴方には、会うべき御方がいる。

literally: You should-meet friend exists(anim.).
means: there is someone who should meet you.

> 貴方には、会うべき御方がいるはずでだ。

literally: You should-meet friend exists(anim.) supposed is ("should-ed" is).
means: it is supposed that someone should meet you.

[image]

---

> According to Jisho.org はずです means

## Tip of the day

It is a reeeealy bad idea to find answers in cases like this in Jisho.
Jisho is a dictinary, not a grammar pattern collection.

The best stratagy is to google with keyword "japanese grammar" + X
In your case it is: **japanese grammar はずです**

And voila - you get the solution!

Comment: It doesn't seem like you translated べき?

Comment: oh, sorry, I'll correct it now. Thanks.